# Showing that something is an inner product

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that:

$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^n{\lambda_j e_j}, \sum_{j=1}^n{\mu_j e_j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j \overline{\mu_j}$$ (where $e_j$ are members of an orthonormal basis) is an inner product.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: well, for starters, you haven't described an inner product; you've described a norm!

Comment: I know that it is a norm, but if $x= \sum_{j=1}^n{\lambda_j e_j}$ can you show that $x$ is an inner product then?

Comment: $x$ is a vector…you can't show that a vector is an inner product. Can you quote the exact question?

Comment: Isn't the equation in your post just the definition of the norm in an inner product space? You can't prove what is true by definition.

Comment: Since you have not yet seen an answer you can accept, I'll try to rephrase my previous comment. You say that you are trying to show that $||v|| = \sqrt{(v, v)}$. (Here I have simply abbreviated $\sum_{j=1}^n{\lambda_je_j}$ as "$v$.") But how is $||\cdot||$ being defined? If $||v||$ is $\sqrt{(v,v)}$ by definition, then what are you trying to prove?

Answer (score 0):

If they are in an orthonormal basis, you have a condition that looks like $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$, and you may induce the norm of some vector $v=\sum_{j=1}^n$ as $\|v\|^2\doteq\langle v,v\rangle$.

In case you have not defined $\langle,\rangle$ for vectors other than the members of the basis, you may do so by imposing linearity, namely as any $v$ can be expressed as above, $\langle v,v\rangle$ can be defined as $\sum_{i,j=1}^n\lambda_i\lambda_j\langle e_i,e_j\rangle$, and that works for any element of the interested vector space.

Then your identity is proven

Comment: make any more sense now?

Comment: I am still confused...

Comment: So I majorly mucked up the original problem. Very sorry. I have now managed to prove the first 3 properties for inner product but am stuck a little on showing that $(x,y)= \overline{(y,x)}$. Any hints?